# Probability She likes Music

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion

1000 people are grouped by their age and hobby. The table is the following:

\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline  & 18-22 & 23-27 & 28-32 & 33-37 & total \\ \hline Music & 54 & 40 & 42 & 66 & 202 \\ \hline Movies & 77 & 68 & 90 & 70 & 305 \\ \hline Walking & 28 & 43 & 50 & 52 & 173 \\ \hline Other & 90 & 78 & 71 & 81 & 320 \\ \hline Total  & 249 & 229 & 253 & 269 & 1000 \\ \hline  \end{array}

You meet a 19-year-old girl who took the survey. What is the probability she prefers music?

---

My approach:

You meet the girl and that girl has $54/249$ of preferring music, that's it.

The question is: Should you use Bayes?

$P(Music|19y) = \frac{P(Music)*P(19y|Music)}{P(19y)}$

$P(Music) = \frac{202}{1000}$

$P(19y|Music) = \frac{54}{249}$

$P(19y) = \frac{249}{1000}$

This would lead to $P = \frac{1212}{6889}$

Comment: why don't you simply ask her directly: "What music do you like best?"  Or "What music do you listen to?" rather than asking Bayes? :-)

Comment: When given a chart like this,  I do the simple thing you did.  Given 19 we are in the restricted universe of the first column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mixed up the denominator for $P(18-22|Music)$, which should equal $\frac{54}{202}$. Then Bayes' Theorem ALSO gives you the right answer: $P(music|18-22) = \frac{P(Music)P(18-22|music)}{P(18-22)}=\frac{\frac{54}{202}\frac{202}{1000}}{\frac{249}{1000}} = \frac{54}{249}$. That said, the first way of doing it is faster.